# Android ListView with custom adapter duplicates List Item

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have a listview that populates data from SQLite using a custom adapter. I use the following adapter.

```
public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomerHolder mHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    if (null == child) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) cContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_info, null);
        mHolder = new CustomerHolder();
        mHolder.ccid = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.ccid);
        mHolder.ccode = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.ttv1);
        mHolder.cname = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.cname);
        mHolder.cspcode = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.cspcode);
        mHolder.ctype = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.ctype);

        child.setTag(mHolder);
    } 
    else 
    {
        mHolder = (CustomerHolder) child.getTag();

    }
    mHolder.ccid.setText(cid.get(pos));
    mHolder.ccode.setText(ccode.get(pos));
    mHolder.cname.setText(cname.get(pos));
    mHolder.cspcode.setText(cspcode.get(pos));
    mHolder.ctype.setText(ctype.get(pos));


    return child;

}

public class CustomerHolder {
    TextView ccid;
    TextView ccode;
    TextView cname;
    TextView cspcode;
    TextView ctype;
}
```

The problem that I face is, the listview populates data, but every list item is duplicated. I have gone through questions in StackOverflow, but, none of the solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked my adapters and only difference from your code is that I instantiate LayoutInflater only once, not on every getView invoke, and I am doing it in on create.

```
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
(...)

public PropertyListAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, 0, new ArrayList<PropertyListItem>());
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    (...)
}
```

Second thing is that my Holder class is static like this:

```
static class AdViewHolder {
    public AdView adView;
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
}
```

Everything else is the same as in your code. Same pattern. So if those changes won't help, try to check if your object/item list doesn't contain the same objects by chance.

Ah and third thing - as my holder is static:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    AdViewHolder adHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
     (...)

}
```

I am nulling it.

Answer (score 0):

That adaptor is fine. You duplicated the data in the database.